# Case Classes with optional fields in Scala

Tags: scala

For example, I have this case class:

```
case class Student (firstName : String, lastName : String)
```

If I use this case class, is it possible that supplying data to the fields inside the case class are optional? For example, I'll do this:

```
val student = new Student(firstName = "Foo")
```

Thanks!

Comment: With case classes, you don't need to use 'new'. It's normally left out.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you just want to miss the second parameter without a default information, I suggest you to use an `Option`.

```
case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String] = None)
```

Now you might create instances this way:

```
Student("Foo")
Student("Foo", None)            // equal to the one above
Student("Foo", Some("Bar"))     // neccesary to add a lastName
```

To make it usable as you wanted it, I will add an implicit:

```
object Student {
  implicit def string2Option(s: String) = Some(s)
}
```

Now you are able to call it those ways:

```
import Student._

Student("Foo")
Student("Foo", None)
Student("Foo", Some("Bar"))
Student("Foo", "Bar")
```

Comment: Noooooooo! Do not use implicit conversions in your code, and especially not between common types like String and Option. If this must be made "easier", add an overload to Student's apply method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you give an explanation ? For all new Scala users here. Just to understand why it is a bad practice ?

Answer (score 36):

You were close:

```
case class Student (firstName : String = "John", lastName : String = "Doe")

val student = Student(firstName = "Foo")
```

Another possibility is partially applied function:

```
case class Student (firstName : String, lastName : String)

val someJohn = Student("John", _: String)
//someJohn: String => Student = <function1>

val johnDoe = someJohn("Doe")
//johnDoe: Student = Student(John,Doe)
```

And to be complete, you can create some default object and then change some field:

```
val johnDeere = johnDoe.copy(lastName="Deere")
//johnDeer: Student = Student(John,Deere)
```

Answer (score 11):

I would see two ways this is normally done.

## 1. default parameters

```
case class Student (firstName : String, lastName : String = "")

Student("jeypijeypi")   # Student(jeypijeypi,)
```

## 2. alternative constructors

```
case class Student (firstName : String, lastName : String)

object Student {
    def apply(firstName: String) = new Student(firstName,"")
}

Student("jeypijeypi")   # Student(jeypijeypi,)
```

Which one is better depends slightly on the circumstances. The latter gives you more freedom: you can make any parameter(s) optional, or even change their order (not recommended). Default parameters need always to be at the end of the parameter list, I think. You can also combine these two ways.

Note: within the alternative constructors you need `new` to point the compiler to the actual constructor. Normally `new` is not used with case classes.