# Case class with empty parameter

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and I am trying to extract few columns based below is my code

```
case class Extract(e1:String,e2:String,e3:String){
   override def toString = e1+","+e2+","+e3
}
object ScalaSpark {
def main(args: Array[String])
{
    val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/File2")
    val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split("\\|"))
    val pid = word.filter(_.contains("SSS"))
    val pidkeys = pid.map(tuple => Extract(tuple(0),tuple(3),tuple(7)))
    val obx = word.filter(_.contains("HHH"))
    val obxkeys = obx.map(tuple => Extract(tuple(0),tuple(5)))
    val rddall = pidkeys.unionAll(obxkeys)
    rddall.saveAsTextFile("/user/xxxx/xxxx/rddsum1")
}
}
```

What I am trying with this code is to extract 3 values from row containing SSS and 2 values from row contatining HHH but when i am executing this i am getting below error

```
error: not enough arguments for method apply: (e1: String, e2: String, e3: String)Extract in object Extract.
```

I then tried using **Opt[String] = None** but that also didn't worked i don't know how to sort out this problem please help.

**EDIT:**

I used **Option[String]** and my code is written below

```
case class Extract(e1:String,e2:String,e3:Option[String]){
   override def toString = e1+","+e2+","+e3
 }
 object ScalaSpark {
def main(args: Array[String])
{
    val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/File2")
    val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
    val pid = word.filter(_.contains("SSS"))
    val pidkeys = pid.map(tuple => Extract(tuple(0),tuple(5),tuple(8)))
    val obx = word.filter(_.contains("HHH"))
    val obxkeys = obx.map(tuple => Extract(tuple(0),tuple(5), None))
    val rddall = pidkeys.union(obxkeys)
    rddall.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/user/xxx/xxx/rddsum1")
}
}
```

but i am getting below error

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Option[String]
           val pidkeys = pid.map(tuple => Header(tuple(0),tuple(5),tuple(8)))
                                                                        ^
<console>:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Extract]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]
Note: Header >: Nothing, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val rddall = pidkeys.union(obxkeys)
```

Comment: Extract expects three args but you are giving only two args here `val obxkeys = obx.map(tuple => Extract(tuple(0),tuple(5)))`

Comment: I tried `case class Extract(e1:String,e2:String,e3:Opt[String]=None )` also but still it is not working.

Comment: plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982474/case-classes-with-optional-fields-in-scala

Comment: The error message is telling you _exactly_ where the problem is.  The 3rd argument is `tuple(8)` when it needs to be `Option(tuple(8))`, or `Some(tuple(8))`, which will also work.

Comment: thanks it helped ! but the result i am getting is `PID,CASTRO^TERESA,Some(F)
OBX,7,None` i dont want **None** and**Some** to be part of my result.

Comment: Well then, extract the data from the `Option` before creating the output string.

Comment: how to do that ? if you just give some sample i am new to scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your `Extract` case class have 3 parameters. Last of them is optional.

If so you should declare it this way:

```
case class Extract(s1: String, s2: String, s3: Option[String])
```

and use it either `Extract("some string", "other string", Some("optional string"))` or `Extract("some string", "other string", None)`.

Comment: I tried but i am getting `error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Option[String]
           val pidkeys = pid.map(tuple => Header(tuple(0),tuple(5),tuple(8)))
                                                                        ^
<console>:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Extract]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]
Note: Header >: Nothing, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val rddall = pidkeys.union(obxkeys)`

Comment: Use `Some(tuple(8)) ` instead of `tuple(8)` as shown in my example.