# Efficient way to create case class with optional fields

Tags: scala

I need to create a case class with optional fields .I refered to [Case Classes with optional fields in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982474/case-classes-with-optional-fields-in-scala)

```
 case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String] = None)
 case class Student1(firstName: String,addd:String,lastName: Option[String] = None,surname:Option[String] = None)
```

1. The way to intialize it ,Is there any other way efficient way  apart from using `Some("Bar")` to initialize it as I have many fields apporx to 15 .

   ```
    Student("Foo")
    Student("Foo", None)            // equal to the one above
    Student("Foo", Some("Bar"))
   ```
2. `print(Student1("Foo","abc",None,Some("abc")))`,I want to have a 
      alternative to None
3. If we iterate through the fields

   ```
        println(Student("Foo").productIterator.mkString("\n"))
   ```

It prints

```
Foo
None
```

I want to remove None

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by `efficient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Overload the `apply()` method.

```
object Student{
  def apply(fn: String, ln: String) = new Student(fn, Option(ln))
}

Student("bob", "jones")  // res0: Student = Student(bob,Some(jones))
Student("ann")           // res1: Student = Student(ann,None)
```

2 - Can't be done.

3 - Override the `toString` method.

```
case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: Option[String] = None) {
  override def toString:String = 
    "Student(" + firstName + lastName.fold("")(",".+) + ")"
}

Student("bob", "jones")  // res0: Student = Student(bob,jones)
Student("ann")           // res1: Student = Student(ann)
```

Comment: in overloading apply method....my number of fields are too many...it gives too many arguments for constructor

Answer (score 1):

For the 1, 2, I think you can use **name with value** to set the `Option` field and skip the fields that you don't want to set, like:

```
Student1("firstname", "add", surname = Some("foo"))
```

For 3, I think you can use filter to skip `None` field, like:

```
s.productIterator.filter(_ match {
    case None => false
    case _ => true
  }).mkString(" ")
```