# Cannot find column using from_json to Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, json4s

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when, from_json, map_keys, map_values}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{MapType, StringType}

case class MyMeta(op: Option[String], table: Option[String])
val metaSchema = Encoders.product[MyMeta].schema

val path = "/FileStore/tables/json_0002C_file.txt"
val df = spark.read.text(path)   
val df2 = df.withColumn("value", from_json(col("value"), MapType(StringType, StringType)))    
val df3 = df2.select(map_values(col("value")))  
val df4 = df3.select($"map_values(value)"(0).as("meta"))  
df4.show(false)
df4.printSchema()
val df5 = df4.withColumn("parsedMeta", from_json(col("meta"), metaSchema)).drop("meta").as[MyMeta]
df5.show(false)
df5.printSchema()
```

returns this:

```
+------------------------------------+
|meta                                |
+------------------------------------+
|{"op":"upd","table":"BILL.PRODUCTS"}|
|{"op":"upd","table":"BILL.PRODUCTS"}|
|{"op":"upd","table":"BILL.SALES"}   |
+------------------------------------+

root
 |-- meta: string (nullable = true)

AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `op` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`parsedMeta`]
```

Cannot see what is wrong here.

For DF it is OK, but not for DS.

```
{  "meta":{    "op":"upd",     "table":"BILL.PRODUCTS"  },  "data":{    "PRICE":"3599"  }, "key":{    "PRODUCT_ID":"230117",    "DESCRIPTION":"Hamsberry vintage tee, cherry",    "PRICE":"4099"  }}
{  "meta":{    "op":"upd",     "table":"BILL.PRODUCTS"  },  "data":{    "PRICE":"4000"  }, "key":{    "PRODUCT_ID":"230117",    "DESCRIPTION":"Hamsberry vintage tee, cherry",    "PRICE":"3599"  }}
{  "meta":{    "op":"upd",     "table":"BILL.SALES"  },  "data":{    "NUM":"20"  }, "key":{    "PRODUCT_ID":"230117",    "DESCRIPTION":"Hamsberry vintage tee, cherry",    "NUM":"10"  }}
```

Comment: can you add a couple of lines of your json_0002C_file.txt file ?

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb  added, but ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case class MyMeta is of type `op: Option[String], table: Option[String]` , this is the type of the column and not the column itself which is named parsedMeta and of type MyMeta, so you need to add the right case class:

```
case class MyMeta2(parsedMeta: MyMeta)
```

Then cast the dataframe to MyMeta2:

```
val df5 = df4.withColumn("parsedMeta", from_json(col("meta"), metaSchema)).drop("meta").as[MyMeta2]
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+
|parsedMeta          |
+--------------------+
|{upd, BILL.PRODUCTS}|
|{upd, BILL.PRODUCTS}|
|{upd, BILL.SALES}   |
+--------------------+
```

**Update**: Full solution:

```
case class MyMeta(op: Option[String], table: Option[String])
case class MyMeta2(parsedMeta: MyMeta)

import spark.implicits._
val metaSchema = Encoders.product[MyMeta].schema

val path = "src/main/resources/input/files/json_0002C_file.txt"
val df = spark.read.text(path)
val df2 = df.withColumn("value", from_json(col("value"), MapType(StringType, StringType)))
val df3 = df2.select(map_values(col("value")))
val df4 = df3.select(col("map_values(value)")(0).as("meta"))
df4.show(false)
df4.printSchema()
val df5 = df4.withColumn("parsedMeta", from_json(col("meta"), metaSchema)).drop("meta").as[MyMeta2]
df5.show(false)
df5.printSchema()
```

**Update 2**: A further explanation

the problem is coming from this piece of code: `.as[MyMeta2]`

You are trying to apply a case class on a dataframe that does not have the same schema.

When applying a schema to a dataframe **it should match exactly with the names and types of columns** of that dataframe.

In you case in this line:

```
val df5 = df4.withColumn("parsedMeta", from_json(col("meta"), metaSchema)).drop("meta").as[MyMeta]
```

You are trying to apply this schema:

```
|-- op: string (nullable = true)
|-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

to a dataframe of this type:

```
 |-- parsedMeta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see there's no column of name parsedMeta in your case class, so it will look for the first attribute which is op and try to match it to your dataframe but will not find it because the root column is called parsedMeta, that's why you got this error:

```
A column or function parameter with name `op` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`parsedMeta`]
```

So you need to apply the right schema, which I defined in my answer as MyMeta2.

How to avoid schema problem in the future:

Create a schema from your case class like this, and then print it:

```
val metaSchema = Encoders.product[MyMeta].schema
metaSchema.printTreeString()
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

Then print the schema of the dataframe you want to apply the schema on:

```
df4.withColumn("parsedMeta", from_json(col("meta"), metaSchema)).drop("meta").printSchema()
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- parsedMeta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

If the schemas are not matching the names and types of every attribute, then you will get an error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Out. Need to think on this.

Comment: Think I get it. Why is DF ok?

Comment: Because for your dataframe you don't apply a schema unlike your dataset

Comment: Ok i will look later when at home.

Comment: I misread from another question lookign for a simplification and indeed I overlooked the Option[]...vs Case class with optional fields.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with optional fields you can keep them, I update the answer with the full solution maybe I was unclear.

Comment: I can't say I am 100%  clear on why. I took this from the edit person of the question. I will further study.

Comment: Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: I would be prepared to give an upvote, but the explanation and what I can find in Scala books are not clear.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982474/case-classes-with-optional-fields-in-scala the 36 upvoted answer. Same approach I had. I think. So...

Comment: @thebluephantom thanks, I updated my answer again, I hope it's more clear now

Comment: I have been experimenting myself. I am wondering if some things have changed. I had an old example that no longer works or it is an example that i stored that never actually worked. Noted the encoder with and without schema.

Comment: The parsedMeta i thought was just the  new column name. Interesting.